# LinearLayout gets children change selector state on focus

Tags: android, selector, android-linearlayout, onfocus

I have a Horizontal Layout in which some vertical layouts are dispatched.

I want to catch the onFocusEvent of my vertical layouts so when one of them gets focus, the image and the textview contained in the vertical layout changes the selector states.

I tried to test it with catching the event OnFocusChange like this :

```
LLContact.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (hasFocus == true) {

            // Has Focus

        } else {

            // Loses focus

        }

        }
    });
```

But the event is never triggered.

I set my linear layout to "FocusableInTouchMode" as true, and Focusable as true as well, but it seems the event never happens ... Do you have any clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which method are you putting this code in?

Comment: The method is put on the onCreate after the setContentView of my activity, and after assigning LLContact to my LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set following properties of childs of manager textview and imageview:
`focusable=false;
clickable=false;
focusable in touch mode=false;`

and set these properties of layout to true;

Comment: Thanks, I think it answers my question ! By the way, the behavior is not exactly what I expected. In fact, I want that when I move the finger on the LinearLayout, the state "focused" is set, and when my finger leaves the LinearLayout, it sets the state of the LinearLayout to "normal". Is the event different from OnFocusChange ?

Comment: Then You can set selector as listSelector property in layout of listView, and dont need to override onFocusChange method

Comment: Isn't this the default!